# Show notifications in custom Android app about posts to a specific page in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an Android app to a page I have on Facebook.
In this app I will show the latest posts (via the Graph API) and some extra data.
I want that the app will give notification when a new post is added to the page in Facebook, is there any way of doing it?
I am new to Android development but I thought that if there is no such option in Facebook API perhaps I can run my app as a service and check the posts regularly and every time I detect a new post my app will give a notification. Will this work? will the user be able to stop me from doing it?
Thanks

Comment: Check out the Real-Time Updates feature of the API. (You will need a server-side component to be able to use those though.)

Comment: Thanks, please add it as an answer so I can mark it as an approved answer. I wish Facebook would allow such feature without forcing me to create a server but I understand why they don't want to, it is a mess for them to start pushing notifications to all the apps (not to mention the traffic and resources overhead). Thank you again for this great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Real-Time Updates feature of the API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4:

> “The Graph API has a feature called 'Real Time Updates' that enables apps to subscribe to changes in certain pieces of data. When a change occurs, an HTTP 'POST' request will be sent to a callback URL belonging to that app. This makes apps more efficient, as they know exactly when a change has happened, and don't need to rely on continuous or even periodic Graph API requests when changes aren't happening.”

(You will need a server-side component to be able to use those though.)